# Mount the encrypted home using mount passphrase

Tags: mount, encryption, data-recovery, passphrase

Hello Ubuntu lovers :)

I need help I feel like I lost documents I worked on for 2 long years, it's a huge problem to me even if it looks simple.
here is my issue :

I'm using Ubuntu desktop, 18.04 LTS

when I enter my password trying to login, the screen becomes black for 5 seconds then comes up again with the login screen ... login loop
so when I tried to access tty1
I found this message :

Signature not found in user keyring

Perhaps try the interactive 'ecryptfs-mount-private'

I issued 'ecryptfs-mount-private', but it asks for the Login passphrase, I don't remember it , it's maybe one of my old password that I changed so many times but I still have the Passphrase, I mean the "mount passphrase"
the mount passphrase actually is the encryption key, wrapped (encoded) using login passphrase.
and I know my password I can access tty
I can't remember the "Login passphrase".
is there any way to mount the encrypted home directly using the mount passphrase, without the login passphrase ? or disable the encryption so I can access my home. if possible disable the encryption without deleting any file ???

Comment: I don't use ecryptfs, but it should be possible to mount using the **unwrapped** mount passphrase directly, as described in [ecryptfs-mount-private is using login passphrase instead of mount passphrase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32204693/4440445), **Option 2: Using low-level mounting**. See also [ecryptfs and login passphrase vs mount passphrase](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692628/ecryptfs-and-login-passphrase-vs-mount-passphrase). Good luck.

Comment: thank you
so is it safe to issue this ?
mount -t ecryptfs ~/.Private ~/Private

cause he said : Even if the two directories were empty, this command only can effectively work for setting up new one in those custom directories, but it is advised when using it to setup a new encrypted directory not to use it with standard Private and .Private directories so as not to cause incompatibilities with standard ecryptfs-utils auto-mounting.

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.